# How to add Date picker in Action Sheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uidatepicker

```
- (IBAction) showCatPicker {

    if (self.catList !=nil) {
        self.catList=nil;
        [catList release];
    }
    self.catList =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];   
    [self.actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);   
    if(self.catPicker == nil) {     
        self.catPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

        self.catPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        self.catPicker.dataSource = self;
        self.catPicker.opaque = YES;
        self.catPicker.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        self.catPicker.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.catPicker.delegate = self;     
    }

    [self.actionSheet addSubview:self.catPicker];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Select"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255 green:122.0/255 blue:53.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissGenderPicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    UISegmentedControl *cancelButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Cancel"]];
    cancelButton.momentary = YES; 
    cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    cancelButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    cancelButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255 green:122.0/255 blue:53.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.actionSheet addSubview:cancelButton]; 
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [cancelButton release]; 
    [closeButton release];  
    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];    
    [self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
    [catPicker reloadComponent:0];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely NOT use UIActionSheet to hold an UIDatePicker because this functionality is deprecated!

From the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/index.html):

> Subclassing Notes
>
> UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add
>   views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more
>   customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create
>   your own and present it modally with
>   presentViewController:animated:completion:.

and

> Important: UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that
>   UIActionSheetDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage action
>   sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a
>   preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

What you could very easily do is to create an UIView to hold the UIDatePicker and animate the view  as appropriate. You can even add an UIToolbar to it if you need to.

Here's an example:

Create two properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *theDatePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *pickerView;
```

Create your picker, embed it into the `UIView` and show:

```
    -(void) createDatePickerAndShow {

        UIToolbar *controlToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        [controlToolbar sizeToFit];

        UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet)];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDateSet)];

        [controlToolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, setButton, nil] animated:NO];


        [theDatePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, controlToolbar.frame.size.height - 15, theDatePicker.frame.size.width, theDatePicker.frame.size.height)];

        if (!pickerView) {
            pickerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:theDatePicker.frame];
        } else {
            [pickerView setHidden:NO];
        }


        CGFloat pickerViewYpositionHidden = self.view.frame.size.height + pickerView.frame.size.height;

        CGFloat pickerViewYposition = self.view.frame.size.height - pickerView.frame.size.height;

        [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerView.frame.origin.x,
                                        pickerViewYpositionHidden,
                                        pickerView.frame.size.width,
                                        pickerView.frame.size.height)];
        [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [pickerView addSubview:controlToolbar];
        [pickerView addSubview:theDatePicker];
        [theDatePicker setHidden:NO];


        [self.view addSubview:pickerView];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{
                             [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerView.frame.origin.x,
                                                             pickerViewYposition,
                                                             pickerView.frame.size.width,
                                                             pickerView.frame.size.height)];
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    }

And to dismiss the DatePicker:

    -(void) cancelDateSet {    
    CGFloat pickerViewYpositionHidden = self.view.frame.size.height + pickerView.frame.size.height;    

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                         animations:^{
                             [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(pickerView.frame.origin.x,
                                                             pickerViewYpositionHidden,
                                                             pickerView.frame.size.width,
                                                             pickerView.frame.size.height)];
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely right, I agree with you because iOS 8 forbids now adding subviews to UIActionSheet and display a modal empty view which can't be dismissed from your app, unless you kill it !

Comment: So should this work? Might doing something wrong somewhere, but I dont get anything on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.blurView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.blurView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self.blurView setAlpha:0.3];
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window addSubview:self.blurView];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [pickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    __block CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 220);
    self.viewForPicker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.viewForPicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.viewForPicker addSubview:pickerView];
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self.viewForPicker];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 15, 60, 30)];
    [button.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
    [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [button.layer setBorderColor:[[IMAppStyle appColor] CGColor]];
    [self.viewForPicker addSubview:button];
    [self.viewForPicker.layer setCornerRadius:8.0];

    float animationDuration = 0.25;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        frame.origin.y -= (180+40+35);
        [self.viewForPicker setFrame:frame];
    }];
```